# How to edit existing item library with Infopath form SP 2013

Tags: infopath, library

I have a SP Library and I publish an Infopath form, when I create a new item, everything works perfect but if I want to edit the item it does not open the same form with the info populated to edit, it opens a default SP form with some fields but the whole form. I'm including the form it opens when editing.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you try to edit the item via:

[image]

If that is the case then the following might help:

In an InfoPath Form Library there are no dedicated InfoPath-forms for Edit and Display.

What you have is

- the one InfoPath-form template that you have created, which is
  displayed when you create a new item or click the title of an existing item or click "Edit in Browser" in the ECB
- DispForm.aspx (aspx-form) to show the item's properties
- EditForm.aspx (aspx-form) to edit the item's properties

When you open that item through a click on it's title or through "Edit in Browser" in the ECB it will open that item as InfoPath-form and you can do your edits from there.

What I usually do is that I create an additional View in my template that is shown by default when an existing item is opened. This view is read-only and therefore mimics the default SharePoint-behaviour of showing DispForm.aspx when you open an item. In order to change the view automatically when an item is opened, I add some code to the Load-event. I have a required field in my form and if this field is populated during the load then the code changes the view to the new one.